# maximal element of a relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X = \mathbb{N}$. We define a relation $\preceq$ on X by: $x \preceq y$ if and only if there is $z ∈ X$ with $xz = y$.

I am trying to find the maximal element(s) in this relation. Currently, I have been able to deduce that the minimal element is $1$ because the domain of $X$ is the set of natural numbers starting from 1.

How do you find the maximal element(s)?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that there are no maximal elements? Also note that your argument that $1$ is the minimal element is not very formal. You have to show that if $x \preceq 1$ then $x = 1$.

Comment: As a note, your relation is called the divisibility relation.  Also, is $0\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes $0\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch if we take x = 1, then for each y we can take z = y and this shows that 1 is less than every other element. Would this be a more formal argument?

Comment: Well, you showed that $1$ is a smallest element, that is, $1 \preceq x$ for all $x$. This is not the same as being a minimal element, even though being a smallest element implies being a minimal element if your relation $\preceq$ is antisymmetric (which is the case here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a maximal element $z\in \mathbb{N}$ under your relation $\preceq$ must satisfy the following: for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$, if $z\preceq x$, then $z=x$.  In other words, if $zy=x$, then $z=x$.  Given any $y\in\mathbb{N}$, we can determine an $x$ such that $z\preceq x$ by simply multiplying $z$ and $y$.  The only way we can ensure that we never get a distinct element is if $zy=z$ for every $y$.  Which $z$ satisfy this?  Ultimately, the only such $z$ is $0$, because $0y=0$.

This means that under $\preceq$, $\mathbb{N}$ has the unique maximal element (i.e. a maximum) $0$.

(Note that with the above reasoning, we can also see that there are no maximal elements when $0\notin \mathbb{N}$.)

Another approach to show that $0$ is a maximum, if we had known to look at $0$ in the first place, is by showing directly that given any $x\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $x\preceq 0$.  This we see by noticing that $0x=0$.